# Showing that $X * Y$ is homotopically equivalent to $\sum (X \wedge Y)$ .

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-writing, homotopy-theory

Showing that $X * Y$ is homotopically equivalent to $\sum (X \wedge Y)$ . I am really stuck in this problem and any help will be greatly appreciated.

**An Edit:**

I was looking at the properties of the join from Wikipedia and I found the following property :

> [image]

However,I do not understand why if $A * {b_{0}} \cup {a_{0}}*B $ is contractible then we are sure that there is a homotopy equivalence between $X * Y$ and $\sum (X \wedge Y)$, could anyone explain for me this, is there is a theorem relating contractibility to homotopy equivalence?

Comment: To make your question self-contained, could you remind what operations "$*$", "$\Sigma$", and "$\wedge$" represent?

Comment: $\sum$ is the reduced suspension and "\wedge " is the smash product.@EricTowers

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_(topology)  @EricTowers

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smash_product @EricTowers

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(topology) @EricTowers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Allen Hatcher, "Algebraic Topology" Proposition 0.17:

> **Proposition 0.17.** If the pair $(X, A)$ satisfies the homotopy extension property and
>   $A$ is contractible, then the quotient map $q:X\to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Note that for CW complexes it is enough if $A$ is a closed subcomplex (which happens here).

Comment: Could you please include what is $X$ and what is $A$ and how they satisfy HEP and how to calculate their quotient

Comment: @Emptymind so $X$ is $A*B$ while $A$ is $A*\{b_0\}\cup\{a_0\}*B$. These are both CW (while OP didn't say it explicitly, it is assumed in the wiki he refers to), and the latter is a closed subcomplex of the former. For CW complexes this is enough to conclude that the pair has HEP. Additionally $A*\{b_0\}\cup\{a_0\}*B$ is contractible, and so the quotient map is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Can you please say why for CW complexes this is enough to conclude that the pair has HEP? is there a theorem about this? or a proof for this?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ in our case here assumed to be closed?

Comment: Yes, there's a theorem that a CW complex together with a closed subcomplex (a.k.a. CW pair) has HEP. This can be found somewhere in Hatchers book (he uses the term "good pair"), but you can also just google it.

Comment: $A*\{b_0\}$ and $\{a_0\}* B$ are always closed in $A*B$, at least when points are closed (which is the case for CW complexes). This follows almost directly from the construction.

Comment: Yeah I think it is proposition 0.16 on pg. 15 of Hatcher's book

Comment: but how is the quotient homeomorphic to the reduced suspension ....... can you please give us the explicit homeomorphism?

Comment: @Emptymind it was quite some time ago, but I think the question was more about the homotopy equivalence of the quotient map, rather than the homeomorphism that follows. Still, the natural candidate is $f:A\times B\times[0,1]\to \Sigma(A\wedge B)$, $f(x,y,t)=[x,y,t]$. I think it is easy to see that it induces a bijection for appropriate quotients. Showing that it induces a homeomorphism might be a tedious task though, I didn't go through the details.