# prove that the reduced join of 2 spaces is homeomorphic to the reduced suspension of the smash of them.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory

Here is what I want to prove:

$$X \star Y \cong \Sigma (X \wedge Y) $$

Could anyone give me a hint about how to prove this, please?

**EDIT:**

I corrected the title of the question to **reduced** join not join only because the first version of the question statement was wrong.

Now I need a proof for the corrected version.

**EDIT:**

The proof that $$X * Y \simeq \Sigma (X \wedge Y) \quad \quad (1)$$ is also acceptable if someone can help me in proving so.

**EDIT:**

I found this question here [Showing that $X * Y$ is homotopically equivalent to $\sum (X \wedge Y)$ .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3354726/showing-that-x-y-is-homotopically-equivalent-to-sum-x-wedge-y) but the answer that is given does not fit for me as I did not studied the homotopy extension property yet.

**EDIT:**

Also, I got a hint in the proof of $(1)$ to use Prop. $4I.1$ on pg.467 of AT which states that:

If $X$ and $Y$ are CW complexes, then $$\sum (X \times Y) \simeq \sum X  \vee \sum Y \vee \sum (X \wedge Y).$$

But still, I do not know how to use it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is false. Take $X = Y = \{*\}$. Then $X \star Y \cong [0,1]$ while $\Sigma(X\wedge Y) \cong \{*\}$. They are homotopy equivalent though, which also holds for CW-complexes in general. Not sure if it holds for general topological spaces, but probably.

Comment: @JensRenders so it must be the reduced join for the statement to be correct?

Comment: Yes that would make sense.

Comment: Yes that holds in general for compact Hausdorff spaces as shown [here](http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/topgrpds-e.pdf), page 180, theorem 5.8.4

Comment: @JensRenders I am  sorry if this question is not related to the original question, but how did you attach this book? most of the time I am posting here I need to attach a document but I do not know how.

Comment: I didn't attach a file, I just posted a link (that book was already online). You can add a link like this: `[link text](link adres)`.

Comment: @JensRenders I have read the proof but I do not fully understand it ..... could you  please post an answer to explain the proof in a simpler way?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with topological K-theory, or at least no more so than it has to do with algebraic topology in general.  Please stop adding irrelevant tags.

Comment: It would also be much clearer what you want from an answer if you explained exactly *what* you don't understand of the proof Jens Renders linked.

Comment: Ok I am sorry for the wrong tag I thought they are related @EricWofsey

Comment: @EricWofsey for your second comment ok  I will be specific about exactly what do I do not understand by editing my question tomorrow.

Comment: @EricWofsey I do not understand many of the ideas of the book. honestly I understand nothing. So sorry to say this but this is my mind.